# Screenshot Software recommendation - free, Windows XP/7

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, software-rec, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free screenshot program that respects Aero's transparency layer](https://superuser.com/questions/148738/free-screenshot-program-that-respects-aeros-transparency-layer)

I had been using a nifty piece of software called PrintKey2000 5.10, which ran on XP, Vista, and 7. It is no longer available and the following version is not free.

It has the ability to use and activate upon using the PrtScrn key, the ALT+PrtScrn key, and a feature that allows you to select a specific region on your screen.

Is there any comparable light-weight screenshot application that is free and has these three features and works on XP/7?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with preserving transparency.

Comment: But the responses in that question are applicable (and are probably going to be repeated) here.

Comment: There are bunch of decent software mentioned there. @Ash nails it.

Comment: A single specific feature does not qualify a question for not being a duplicate. Duplicates are not just about the questions, but the answers it will attract. Keep this in mind in future.

Comment: It is hard to understand why so many of you think the question is duplicated. You've neglect the chance that good screenshot program that cannot handle transparency appear as the answer. And, 2 questions are even mentioning different OS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows 7 comes with the [snipping tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Use-Snipping-Tool-to-capture-screen-shots), which can be [activated via hotkey](https://superuser.com/questions/137636/cannot-get-windows-snipping-tool-to-auto-run-with-autohotkey) with a little tweaking.

Some nifty third party tools include [Cropper](http://cropper.codeplex.com/):

[image]

[Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org):

[image]

and of course, [Gadwin](http://www.gadwin.com/printscreen/).

Comment: This is not available on XP. I'm looking for something that will work for both operating systems.

Comment: Read on ..... :)

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying out Greenshot and it has some nice features I like :)

Answer (score 2):

My favourite: **[FSCapture 5.3](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=775)** (last free version)

Portable, lightweight, free.

[image: FSCapture 5.3]

Answer (score 1):

Use [Irfan View](http://www.irfanview.com/main_download_engl.htm), is is faster than XnView and allows to set up a capture hotkey, or start capturing with a delay (possible via hotkey too).

Answer (score 0):

I know you are looking for a free solution; this is more of an FYI, in case you have Microsoft OneNote...

You can press Win - S to take a screenshot that is pasted inside the OneNote program...Then right-click the image (while it is selected), and click "Save As".  You can then save the image anywhere you like...