# How to take a screenshot on Windows 7 and auto create screenshot file on desktop like Mac?

Tags: windows-7, screenshot

I'm trying to find information how do we take a screenshot on Windows 7 that will actually create a screenshot file like `.png` in to your desktop like on mac where you can do it by pressing <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>.

[image: Mac keyboard with command, shift, and 4 keys highlighted]

In windows all I know is that I can do it by press <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> = Windows captures the entire screen and copies it to the clipboard.

or for the Active windows I can just do hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> = Windows captures only the currently active window and copies it to the clipboard.

Right now I'm using `maComFort` which it gives me the functionality of Mac-like keyboard that I can take a screenshot in such the same way with Mac OS X but really it changes many of the keys in my keyboard in the way I don't like.

So I wonder if there is a better way?

Comment: I read that on Windows 8 you can do `Win` + `PrtScrn` and it saves it in your user profile folder under pictures.

Comment: 1. Open Picasa and minimize it.

2. Now, hit “Print Screen” key to capture the screen

3. Screenshots will automatically get saved in the “Pictures” folder

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use [Screenpresso](http://www.screenpresso.com). It's free, portable and only uses the Print key (with modifiers).

Comment: Could you perhaps tell us something more about Screenpresso?

Comment: I got this and set it to Ctrl+PrintScreen, it Auto saves to a folder and does not get in the way. It also has tonnes of other useful features such as capturing video.

Comment: Requires internet connection. No portable app that does nothing more than take a screenshot should require an internet connection to function.

Comment: I've just got Screenpresso but can't get it to prompt me for the filename before saving.  is this possible?

Comment: Now it needs .NET crap, and it's about 13 MB, and it requires internet connection.

Comment: I installed it, and AFAICT there's no way to set it up to do what the asker wants: press a key, get a .png. The whole point is no interaction, just capture.

Answer (score 13):

Download [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html), [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and Install them both. (Copy nircmd files to either Windows directory or extract it to a new folder).

Change this to relevant directories where the nircmd executable is stored and the path to your desktop.

```
c:\path\to\nircmd.exe savescreenshot c:\path\to\desktop\Screenshot.png
```

If everything goes fine, you should see a screenshot on your desktop. Now to make PrintScreen to execute that command. This is where AutoHotKey comes in.

I just modified the Script [found here](https://superuser.com/questions/137636/cannot-get-windows-snipping-tool-to-auto-run-with-autohotkey). Create a new ".ahk" file using Notepad, Paste this and modify as needed.

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir, path:\to\desktop

PRINTSCREEN::Run, c:\path\to\nircmd.exe savescreenshot c:\path\to\desktop\Screenshot_%A_Now%.png
!PRINTSCREEN::Run, c:\path\to\nircmd.exe savescreenshotwin c:\path\to\desktop\Screenshot_%A_Now%.png
return
```

Now use the "Convert .ahk to .exe" tool which is installed along with AutoHotKey and create a executable.

Run that executable and press PrintScreen (and Alt+PrintScreen); See if that did the job.

Now just add a shortcut to that executable to your Startup folder (which automatically loads it whenever you boot).

Edit: Modified to add Alt+Printscreen and Timestamp to files.

Comment: Sorry for second post. Enter key did not work as expected.

I specifically came here looking for a screen capture solution with no "Save As" prompt. Not sure if OP wanted a solution with or without a prompt, but I'm upvoting this as an equally correct alternate answer.

Note for the installer averse: You do not need the entire AutoHotKey bundle for this solution, useful as it all may be. You only need the compiler, Ahk2Exe.exe, which can be downloaded as a standalone executable. The command to create the executable from script is "Ahk2Exe.exe /in a:\path\to\your_script.ahk".

Comment: If you still want the image to be in the clipboard too, prepend a tilde to the hotkey statement like, "~PRINTSCREEN::Run, ...." That passes the keypress through to the OS like usual, in addition to triggering the hotkey.

Comment: What does the `!PRINTSCREEN:: ... ` line do? What is the purpose of the leading exclamation point?

Answer (score 12):

Simply use the built in Snipping Tool. It will capture the screen and prompt you to save it to a .png file. If you want it to run when you hit <kbd>PrintScrn</kbd> then bind it to that key using AutoHotKey.

Comment: To whom it may be interested, you could also add a shortcut to the Snipping Tool, something like `CTRL+ALT+P`. To do this, just **right** click on "Start > All Programs > Accessories > Snipping Tool" and select "Properties", then just click on "Shortcut Key" and add `CTRL+ALT+P` (you can't add `PrintScrn` as a shortcut, but at least you won't need to install any external application like AutoHotKey)

Answer (score 6):

You could try Purrint.

http://www.bcheck.net/apps/

It gives you choices on formats to use, based on the extension you give the screengrabs when you first configure the program.  And of course, you can choose where you want the screen shots to go.

Comment: Love that this app has worked since Windows 95, and is only 114kb!

Comment: Perfect solution after hours of search. Thanks! Note for Windows 7, you need to use the later updated version shown in the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

btw if you already happen to use [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/) (which I happened to do, because it's an unbelievably super handy tool for quick editing images and opening/converting between all sorts of image formats), there is an option for starting a Screen Capturing session (Options -> Capture/Screenshot..) (i am attaching the dialog that is displayed, containing all the possible options like the destination directory and the shortcut buttons, as well as the naming and the format of the destination image files)

[edit] at the time of this writing IrfanView is "FREEWARE (for non-commercial use)"

[image: irfanview screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but it seems [FRAPS](https://games.softpedia.com/get/Tools/Fraps.shtml) still has no competition. It lets you set up a destination folder and file format, bind a screenshot key, and lets you capture from fullscreen applications such as games and movie players.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a simple python script to capture the screen to a file on a hot key.

The script and its shortcut are [here](https://github.com/idachev/python-utils/).

There are two files printscreen-win.lnk and printscreen-win.py

Copy both of them to `c:\utils`, that path can be changed but you need to edit the shortcut file.

The shortcut file expects that your python is:

```
c:\Python27\pythonw.exe
```

Copy the shortcut to your Desktop and make a "Shortcut Key" from its Properties.
Default one that I use is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>

Once you execute the script it will save a new screen-shot under `...\Desktop\screen\`

You will need Python 2.x and [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).

Enjoy!