# Single Monitor Screenshot on MultiMonitor setup

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot

From windows 8 on wards there is an easy way to take screenshots <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSC</kbd> key and it automatically saves the screenshot in the pictures library.

I have two monitors and using this shortcut captures the both monitor i just want to capture a single monitor.

I am aware of the method using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSC</kbd> it stores screenshot of the active windows in clipboard. But with this method i have to manually save the screenshot.

I am looking for a way to save screenshot automatically of single monitor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take a screenshot on Windows 7 and auto create screenshot file on desktop like Mac?](http://superuser.com/questions/412293/how-to-take-a-screenshot-on-windows-7-and-auto-create-screenshot-file-on-desktop)

Answer (score 3):

In Creators update, Windows 10, I like this: Windows key + Shift + S. That enables you to drag a rectangle, and if your monitors are set up so that moving the cursor to the corner stops it, you can get an exact full screen easily.

Comment: then what happens to it?

Comment: It's been magically copied to the clipboard. Open Paint, type Ctrl-v and it'll be inserted into your image.

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> method to screenshot one monitor will work if you use Dropbox.

To enable Dropbox to automatically capture screenshots:

1. Click the Dropbox icon in your menu bar.
2. Click the *gear icon* and select *Preferences*… from the menu.
3. Click the *Import* tab.
4. Check or uncheck *Share screenshots using Dropbox*.

Comment: This will work regardless of Dropbox. Alt + PrtScn will always capture the screenshot of the current window though. This means that if you're in fullscreen mode (eg. videogame) or in window mode while having that particular window in focus it's going to work just fine, while if you're focusing your desktop you're going to end with the whole extended desktop screenshot (all monitors combined)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Snipping Tool in Windows 7 upwards.

Capture part or all of your PC screen, add notes, save the snip, or email it right from the Snipping Tool window. You can capture any of the following types of snips:

- Free-form Snip. Draw a free-form shape around an object.
- Rectangular Snip. Drag the cursor around an object to form a
  rectangle.
- Window Snip. Select a window, such as a browser window or dialog box,
  that you want to capture.
- Full-screen Snip. Capture the entire screen.

After you capture a snip, it's automatically copied to the Snipping Tool window. From there, you can annotate, save, or share the snip. The following procedures explain how to use Snipping Tool.

**Capture a snip**

In Snipping Tool, select the arrow next to the New button, choose the kind of snip you want, and then pick the area of your screen that you want to capture.

**Capture a snip of a menu**

After you open Snipping Tool, open the menu that you want a picture of. (For Windows 7, press Esc before opening the menu.)
Press Ctrl + PrtScn.
Select the arrow next to the New button, choose the kind of snip you want, and then pick the area of the screen that you want to capture.

**Annotate a snip**

After you capture a snip, you can write or draw on or around the snip by selecting the Pen button.

**Save a snip**

After you capture a snip, select the Save Snip button.
In the Save As box, enter a file name, location, and type, and then select Save.

**Remove the URL**

When you capture a snip from a browser window and save it as an HTML file, the URL appears below the snip. To prevent the URL from showing up:

In the Snipping Tool, select the Options button.
In the Snipping Tools Options box, clear the Include URL below snips (HTML only) check box, and select OK.

**Share a snip**

After you capture a snip, select the arrow next to the Send Snip button, and then select an option from the list.

Comment: TL;DR:  Use `Mode: Rectangular snip` to make it easier to drag out the desired window. Start in one corner, drag to diagonally opposite corner. Release. Save.